# Removing options from selects when selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to do something in react, where I have days of the week with select options.

When an option is selected on Monday (for example), I want it to not be included in the list for Tuesday and Wednesday.

Quick visual mockup to help visualise. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB8qS.png

Thoughts so far have been to create a new state array called "available", then doing a function onchange of the select, to remove it from the array, and update state to this.

Whilst this works, it also removes it from the selected one…

```js
// function to remove from the list and update state

removeFromList = event => {
    let updatedList = this.state.availableMeals;
    console.log(event.target.value);
    updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(item) {
      return (
        item.fields.Name.toLowerCase().search(
          event.target.value.toLowerCase()
        ) === -1
      );
    });
    this.setState({ availableMeals: updatedList });
```

```js
// from inside the component

<select onChange={this.props.removeFromList}>
            <option>select an option…</option>
            {this.props.meals.map(meal => (
              <option key={meal.id}>{meal.fields.Name}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
```

Any ideas of how to approach something like this?

Thoughts i've had were around storing each day and the selected option to state, then reference that once a selection has been made?

Comment: simple ternary in map `return availablesIncludesOption() ? <option /> : null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better not to remove an option from the list in the state, but filter your options, when you render them:

1. Child Component with dropdown:

```
class DropDown extends React.Component {
    onSelect = event => {
        this.props.selectItem(this.props.name, event.target.value);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
                <option>select an option…</option>
                {this.props.meals.map(meal => (
                    <option key={meal.id} value={meal.id}>{meal.value}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
        );
    }
}
```

2. Parent Component:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            selectedItems: {}
        };
    }

    getFilteredMeals(name) {
        const removedItems = { ...this.state.selectedItems };
        delete removedItems[name];
        const removedItemsList = Object.values(removedItems);
        return this.props.meals.filter(item => {
            return !removedItemsList.includes(item.id);
        });
    }

    getValue(name) {
        return this.state.selectedItems[name];
    }

    selectItem = (name, value) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedItems: {
                ...this.state.selectedItems,
                [name]: value
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DropDown
                    name="monday"
                    selectItem={this.selectItem}
                    meals={this.getFilteredMeals("monday")}
                    value={this.getValue("monday")}
                />
                <DropDown
                    name="tuesday"
                    selectItem={this.selectItem}
                    meals={this.getFilteredMeals("tuesday")}
                    value={this.getValue("tuesday")}
                />
                <DropDown
                    name="wednesday"
                    selectItem={this.selectItem}
                    meals={this.getFilteredMeals("wednesday")}
                    value={this.getValue("wednesday")}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I created a working example for you:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/gallant-murdock-vsibi

Comment: @xadm I have updated my answer with an example for many items.

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko thanks for this! Still quite new to react, so interesting to discover the recommended patterns for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit surprising ... and funny

You have filtered list `this.state.availableMeals` - probably initialized from `this.props.meals` ...

then why not use this for render?

```
{this.state.availableMeals.map(meal => (
  <option key={meal.id}>{meal.fields.Name}</option>
))}
```

Keeping filtered list can be more performant - no need to recalculate during `render`.

Comment: If you filter options for all dropdowns, then your selected option will disappear in dropdown where you select this option.

Comment: You're right ... but not always needed, f.e. render `<Chip/>` (or sth else, one or more) before `<Select/>` - this way we have in select a set of options available to add (append to) or replace currently selected option(-s)